# Does QTP support Checking the code of a Windows application?

Tags: windows, testing, qtp, white-box

Recently I use QTP to test a Windows application, but it can just help me recording the behavior of user-interface and I cann't find the way to inspect the inner logical structure,business procedures and how every class interacts with others through its public attributes and methods. Does QTP support such kind of testing? If not, which tools can I use to make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QTP is designed for UI testing and doesn't support testing code for the application in the question. There are some white-box testing tools that can be used to achieve it like GTest, VS testing tools.